# Visual studio not loading module (therefore no breakpoints to hit)

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2019

I have a Solution with the following structure:

- Services (.sln)

  - **ServiceImplementation**
  - ServiceLogic

I've **boldened** the startup project.

ServiceImplementation references ServiceLogic with a project reference and contains code that instantiates an object within ServiceLogic.

When the solution is started ServiceImplementation has the following command line argument `/client:"WcfTestClient.exe"` and the application functionally works fine.

However any breakpoints placed in ServiceLogic will not be hit, in addition it doesn't display in the Modules window nor ProcessExplorer so the assumption must be it isn't running, but as I said the application works.

I've cleaned, rebuilt and confirmed locations to no avail.  I'd love to hear any suggestions.

Comment: make sure that you are running in debug mode. you can verify this from the top bar it's must show Debug and not "Release"

Comment: Yep, we're in debug

Comment: Just a suggestion: as I understand, ServiceImplementation is a WCF client, while ServiceLogic is the server. So you start the client with a reference to the server dll, but when the client calls a server method, there is no hosted server to process it. Can it be you need Multiple Startup projects?

Comment: Conceptually correct yes although they all run within the one solution and it works functionally (so it must be running)

Comment: They do run in the same solution, but it should be another process for the server, which runs, but the debug session is not attached to it. If Multiple Startup didn't work, I would try running it and than selecting Debug->Attach to Process and looking for the process where WCF server is hosted.